# Java minecraft jar extension

Tags: java, minecraft

I know minecraft is written in Java, and that Java cannot be changed to exe files. Yet, when I download minecraft, it says minecraft.exe and runs as an exe file, not a CLASS file. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You can use an executable wrapper around Java program. See [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file? \[closed\]][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Answer (score 6):

The `Minecraft.exe` you download is unrelated to the actual Minecraft game, it's simply a launcher which is used to download and run the Minecraft version you select.

The version of the game you're running is downloaded to `.minecraft/versions/<VERSION>/<VERSION>.jar`. e.g. `.minecraft/versions/1.6.4/1.6.4.jar`

Answer (score 0):

MrLore's Answer above is correct. If you download the app from minecraft.net, you are probably going to get the .exe if you download the first link there; there is also another option for downloading it as a jar, at which point you can run the following in the directory you've downloaded the java package in:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

This is necessary for operating systems that do not have built-in .exe support, such as OSX or any UNIX-based system.